# How do I transfer multiple files with a common suffix and prefix using an offset?

Tags: regular-expression, sftp

I have thousands of files whose names are of the form:

```
sequence_1_0001.hmf  
sequence_1_0002.hmf  
sequence_1_0003.hmf
...  

sequence_1_0001.jpg  
sequence_1_0002.jpg
sequence_1_0003.jpg
...  

sequence_2_0001.hmf  
sequence_2_0002.hmf  
sequence_2_0003.hmf
...
```

etc..

I'm using sftp to transfer only the files whose suffix and prefix are 'sequence_1' and '.hmf', respectively.  However, I don't want to transfer all the files that match this format.  Instead, I want to transfer every hundreth file.  That is:

```
sequence_2_0001.hmf  
sequence_2_0101.hmf  
sequence_2_0201.hmf
...
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: For your specific case, wouldn't 'sequence_1' and '01.jpg' as prefix and suffix work?

Comment: @DeepakMittal: I'm not sure what you mean... could you elaborate?

Comment: You said you're using sftp with prefix and suffic as 'sequence_1' and '.jpg' respectively. So just change suffix to '01.jpg' and it would work, right?. The only accepted files then would be sequence_1_xx01.jpg, where xx can be any number/character.

Comment: You may want to double-check your copy pasted sections for consistency since some of it still mentions `.hmf` and the wrong `sequence_` prefix.

Comment: @jw013: Thanks for the heads up... I fixed the question so that it has 'hmf', as I meant to put :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples and description are inconsistent. Going by the list `sequence_2_0001.hmf`, `sequence_2_0101.hmf`, `sequence_2_0201.hmf`, …, you can use the `?` wildcard to match any one character.

```
get sequence_2_??01.hmf
```

You can use character sets to match one file every 20 (for example). `[02468]` matches any one of the digits `0`, `2`, `4`, `6` or `8`.

```
get sequence_2_[02468]?01.hmf
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the file list with something like this:

```
printf %s\\n sequence_[0-9]*.jpg | sort -t_ -k2n | sed -n '1~100p'
```

Comment: When possible, it's best to avoid making assumptions about file names, but otherwise.  Assumptions such as file names being newline delimited should be *clearly* advertised.  `first~step` is a GNU extension to `sed` line-addressing, and not widely portable.  The `-n` in `sort` is not useful because the file names here are prefixed by a string and the numeric portions are properly padded anyways.  The `find` will likely go deeper than the OP intended.  In this particular special case, the approach in @Gilles' answer and @DeepakMittal's comment is much more efficient and robust.

Comment: @jw013, the OP specifically mentioned the filename template. I intended `sort -n` to sort sequence_1, sequence_2 ... sequence_10 correctly, but it should have been `sort -t_ -k2n`. Other than that I agree with your comments.